# Cannot install/find/use e2fsprogs

Tags: linux, bash, debian, gparted

I need this executable:

```
e2fsprogs
```

I cannot find it on my system; from the console (even with sudo) I get "bash: e2fsprogs: command not found".
With a search, all I get is its documentation (in `/usr/share/doc/e2fsprogs`).

Trying to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install e2fsprogs
```

I get the message "e2fsprogs is already the newest version", and nothing is done.

Trying to uninstall it (for a subsequent re-installation):

```
sudo apt-get remove e2fsprogs
```

I get the frightening message "You are about to do something potentially harmful. To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'"

How can I use this command? How can I find it?

---

This command is needed by the `gparted` utility to resize disk partitions.

Trying to reduce the size of /dev/sda7 (bios_grub) by 500 MiB, I get the message:

- Error: The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support:  e2fsprogs v1.41+.

---

Output of `dpkg -l e2fsprogs`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version               Architecture          Description
+++-================================-=====================-=====================-====================================
ii  e2fsprogs                        1.42.12-2             amd64                 ext2/ext3/ext4 file system utilities
```

Comment: Please include the output of `dpkg -l e2fsprogs`

Comment: So this is a very XY-y problem. First, you misread the error message. It clearly mentions a missing *software package*, not command. Then, your actual question is: Why can I not resize the partition? That’s because the GPT BIOS Boot partition does not have a file system. Please ask a new(!) question and provide the output of `parted /dev/sda print`.

Comment: @DanielB: `parted` seems to be another package. Which command should I launch?

Comment: Gparted uses parted. I already wrote the exact command of interest.

Comment: This is the output I get from your command: `bash: parted: command not found`

Answer (score 2):

From the package description (`apt-cache show e2fsprogs`):

> ```
>  This package contains programs for creating, checking, and maintaining
>  ext2/3/4-based file systems.  It also includes the "badbocks" program,
>  which can be used to scan for bad blocks on a disk or other storage device.
> ```

This package contains many utilities for ext2/3/4-based filesystems,
it does not contain a program called "e2fsprogs".
To find the files installed by this package, you can use the `dpkg -L` command, for example:

```
$ dpkg -L e2fsprogs | grep bin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/lsattr
/usr/bin/chattr
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/filefrag
/usr/sbin/e2freefrag
/usr/sbin/mklost+found
/usr/sbin/e4defrag
/sbin
/sbin/debugfs
/sbin/dumpe2fs
/sbin/e2undo
/sbin/mke2fs
/sbin/resize2fs
/sbin/e2fsck
/sbin/badblocks
/sbin/e2image
/sbin/logsave
/sbin/tune2fs
/sbin/mkfs.ext2
/sbin/mkfs.ext4
/sbin/e2label
/sbin/mkfs.ext4dev
/sbin/fsck.ext2
/sbin/mkfs.ext3
/sbin/fsck.ext4dev
/sbin/fsck.ext4
/sbin/fsck.ext3
```

I filtered the output to see only the paths containing "bin",
which is typical of binary files.
Most certainly it's one of these programs that you need for your purpose (which you have not explained).

---

> Error: The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support: e2fsprogs v1.41+.

This error message doesn't mean that `gparted` needs the executable program `e2fsprogs`. It means that it needs the `e2fsprogs` *package*, which contains the binaries it needs. Specifically, it needs at least version 1.41. You can verify the version of your `e2fsprogs` package with:

```
dpkg -l e2fsprogs
```

Comment: I added the purpose in my question.

Comment: I have version 1.42.12-2.

Comment: Hm, so it should be working... The error message says "The following ***list*** of software packages [...]", emphasis mine, was there really just `e2fsprogs` listed there or is there more in the "list" ?

Comment: No, there is nothing else in the list...

Comment: Too bad. I think it would be better to ask a new a question, focusing on why `gparted` refuses to resize the partition, and why it suggests a missing package even though it is actually there.

Comment: [New related question](http://superuser.com/questions/1164222/gparted-refuses-to-resize-partition)