# gparted refuses to resize partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, gparted

gparted refuses to resize a partition, reporting the error:

```
<i>dumpe2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
dumpe2fs: Invalid argument while reading journal super block</i>

<i>Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support:  e2fsprogs v1.41+.</i>
```

The `e2fsprogs` package is installed (version 1.42.12-2).

---

This is the complete error message:

```
File system: ext4
Size: 6.52 GiB
Status: Not mounted

Partition
Path: /dev/sda7
Flag: bios_grub


<i>Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          3821d550-ceaa-4388-8be1-2da5678e0831
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              9371648
Block count:              37468416
Reserved block count:     1873420
Free blocks:              35413208
Free inodes:              9106611
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1015
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Thu Jan  5 01:03:01 2017
Last mount time:          Thu Jan  5 03:04:52 2017
Last write time:          Thu Jan  5 03:04:52 2017
Mount count:              4
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Jan  5 01:03:01 2017
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          13 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      3d766a26-9f5c-442c-9c8e-8e6ff0f5df75
Journal backup:           inode blocks</i>

<i>dumpe2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
dumpe2fs: Invalid argument while reading journal super block</i>

<i>Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support:  e2fsprogs v1.41+.</i>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a broken super-block :`Unable to read the contents of this file system!`

Check your filesystem:

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/sdaX
```

If your filesystem is corrupted , you should have an output like this :`The superblock could not be read....`

Run `mke2fs` command to find out the superblock backups:

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdaX
```

Restore the missing superblock through the `e2fsck` command:

You should use the first superblock obtained from `mke2fs`

```
sudo e2fsck -b put_the_first_block_number_here /dev/sdaX
```

Reboot your system then run `gparted`

Answer (score 1):

similar error:

```
Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support: lvm2.
```

solved:
stop gparted, run `sudo pvs` and use the listed mapper of interest, then run
`sudo pvresize /dev/mapper/sdX_crypt`

restart gparted, error gone